# SSL from GoDaddy showing as "expired" + weird SSL certificate behavior

Tags: security, ssl

At June 24 we experienced very strange issue on our server: SSL certificate (from GoDaddy) occurred as improper... despite nobody changed it. So we just reinstalled it and forgot about the issue.

But today, while reviewed mailer logs, we found very bad things:

Since June 24, our PHP based program was unable to send (almost) any email.
The keyword "almost" prevented me to check these logs earlier - some emails indeed were sent.

```
$sock = fsockopen("ssl://mail.dupcheck.org",993, $errno, $errstr, 300);
```

- this line runs every minute. And if socket was not created, this is written to log, including errno, errstr...
- it returns: $sock = false, errno = 0, errstr = "" quite fast.
- it opens other SSL servers.
- sometimes it opens the socket and sends emails... it does it 1-3 times a day...

There is issue

```
$ openssl s_client -connect mail.dupcheck.org:993
...
Certificate chain
   0 s:/OU=Domain Control Validated/CN=mail.dupcheck.org
   i:/C=US/ST=Arizona/L=Scottsdale/O=GoDaddy.com, 
Inc./OU=http://certs.godaddy.com/repository//CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate 
Authority - G2
...
    Verify return code: 10 (certificate has expired)

    Serial Number:
    92:a0:2d:2a:2f:28:6a:d5
Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
    Issuer: C=US, ST=Arizona, L=Scottsdale, O=GoDaddy.com, Inc., 
OU=http://certs.godaddy.com/repository/, CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate 
Authority - G2
    Validity
        Not Before: Jun 24 10:16:38 2016 GMT
        Not After : Jun 24 10:16:38 2019 GMT
```

Despite explicitly this certificate WAS up to 2023.
So we updated the certificate, but it still shows this ....

Comment: *"was unable to __send__ (almost) any email...`fsockopen("ssl://mail.dupcheck.org",993`..."* -  Port 993 is IMAPS which is only about __receiving__ mail. It has nothing to do with sending the mail at all.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich, you are correct :) It is IMAP. The issue - Zend_Mail_Storage_Imap, which is used in the system, does fsockopen inside its code.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich ANYWAY, I've updated the answer ... and it indeed SSL problem

Comment: *"So we updated the certificate, but it still shows this ..."* - which means likely that the update went wrong or was incomplete. There is no universal "update certificate" procedure which works on all systems and it is unclear what exactly you did compared to what was actually required to do.

Comment: And note that there are different certificates installed on the system. For HTTPS there is a certificate installed which is valid until 2021 while for SMTP and IMAP the expired certificate is installed.